# Nextjs: Blob is not defined when using npm package 'extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blob, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

I'm using 'connect' function from this package, [If I import normally it works fine but I'm getting Blob is not defined since its Nextjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbQj.png)

So, I tried importing it dynamically as below
[Here I'm getting type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgZAn.png)

[Argument of type '() => Promise<(port: globalThis.MessagePort) => Promise>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions | Loader'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJyYL.png)

Then tried to match type
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL8CJ.png)

But now the function is not callable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P10G.png)

This package uses Blob, due to SSR its show Blob is not defined, How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Next.js user but I guess `dynamic()` only works with components.

But `connect()` returns a promise which means you can probably replace the static import with a normal `import()`.

```js
const connect = () => import('extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder')
    .then(({ connect }) => connect())
```

Just make sure `connect()` doesn't actually get called on the server.